# ASP textboxes always returns the original text

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, textbox

I'm having a weird issue with my textboxes on my website.

Currently I'm making a page to allow the customer to update their credentials.
So I have a page that shows that information in textboxes (fetched from the DB in the Page_Load)

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //Ingelogd
    kService = new KlantService();
    ingelogdeKlant = kService.GetAllByUsername(inlogsessie.GetUsername());

    //Gegevens tonen
    begroeting.InnerText = "Welkom " + ingelogdeKlant.voornaam + " " + ingelogdeKlant.achternaam;
    txtVoornaam.Text = ingelogdeKlant.voornaam;
    txtAchternaam.Text = ingelogdeKlant.achternaam;
    txtStraat.Text = ingelogdeKlant.straat;
    txtNummer.Text = Convert.ToString(ingelogdeKlant.nummer);
    txtPostcode.Text = ingelogdeKlant.postcode;
    txtStad.Text = ingelogdeKlant.stad;
}
```

And this is the code I use to get the text from the textboxes and send them to my DB (Trigger = Button click)

```
ingelogdeKlant.voornaam = txtVoornaam.Text;
ingelogdeKlant.achternaam = txtAchternaam.Text;
ingelogdeKlant.straat = txtStraat.Text;
ingelogdeKlant.nummer = Convert.ToInt16(txtNummer.Text);
ingelogdeKlant.postcode = txtPostcode.Text;
ingelogdeKlant.stad = txtStad.Text;

kService = new KlantService();
kService.UpdateKlant(ingelogdeKlant)
```

Tried solution #1:
Remove the IsPostBack check
Result: txtSomething.text returns the original values (not the edited ones)

Tried solution #2:
Adding the IsPostBack check
Result: txtSomething.text returns a nullpointer

I don't know what the issue could be, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your `ingelogdeKlant` is null since you are only instantiating it on `!Page.IsPostBack`.

Comment: My ingelogdeKlant object a global variable, so isn't it "saved" after the page_load? If not: how can I keep the content?

Comment: Try debugging to see if ingelogdeKlant actually has any data.

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint in at ingelogdeKlant.voornaam = txtVoornaam.Text so you can then move through each line and see what is actually being returned by your textboxes as well as what is in ingelogdeKlant at the time it gets sent to kService.UpdateKlant.

Comment: Well, I did exactly that. Check my "solutions" in the original post. Both with postback and without returned wrong data (nullPointer or orignal text)

Comment: What is this Original text? Also please check what ingelogdeKlant is when setting txtVoornaam.txt

Comment: I mean use the debugger, set a breakpoint where I mentioned and then use 'step over' to move through each line of code to evaluate it. Just changing the code and re-running it will mean you take a long time to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, but it has been solved using the solution from @DaveParsons. Still appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the following

```
//Ingelogd
kService = new KlantService();
ingelogdeKlant = kService.GetAllByUsername(inlogsessie.GetUsername());
```

Above the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`

Your `ingelogdeKlant` is only instantiated on the first `Page_Load` and not on subsequent postbacks.

Your Page class is instantiated each time a request (PostBack or not) is made, any members need to be initialised each time they are needed; they won't persist because the Page object doesn't persist.